# getting value from a list

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a xml that looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="1.0" xml:lang="en">
<title type="text">Google Hot Trends</title>
<subtitle type="text">What are people searching for on Google today?</subtitle>
<id>http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly,2007-08</id>
<link href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly" rel="self"/>
<updated>2010-12-01T14:03:30Z</updated>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<id>2010-12-01T14:03:30Z</id>
<title type="text"><![CDATA[rosa parks, adam levine girlfriend, meet the famous, ...]]></title>

<content type="html"><![CDATA[<ol>
<li><span class="Mild up2"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=rosa+parks&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">rosa parks</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down1"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=adam+levine+girlfriend&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">adam levine girlfriend</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down1"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=meet+the+famous&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">meet the famous</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild equal"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=sons+of+anarchy+season+4&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">sons of anarchy season 4</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild equal"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=victoria+secret+angels&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">victoria secret angels</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up5"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=happy+hanukkah&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">happy hanukkah</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down1"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=katy+perry+victoria+secret+fashion+show&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">katy perry victoria secret fashion show</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down1"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=married+to+the+mob+clothing&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">married to the mob clothing</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down1"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=victoria+secret+models+names+and+pictures&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">victoria secret models names and pictures</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild equal"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=world+aids+day+2010&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">world aids day 2010</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up6"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=shahla+jahed&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">shahla jahed</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild equal"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=interpol&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">interpol</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up18"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=wallis+simpson&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">wallis simpson</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up46"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=chanukah&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">chanukah</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild new"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=hiv+symptoms&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">hiv symptoms</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up6"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=santa+tracker&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">santa tracker</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down8"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=vs+fashion+show+2010&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">vs fashion show 2010</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down3"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=advent+calendar&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">advent calendar</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up8"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=december+1&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">december 1</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up19"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=aids+ribbon&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">aids ribbon</a></span></li>
</ol>
]]></content></entry></feed>
```

How would i be able to get the values from the `<a>` tags that are inside the `<li>` tags?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do if your `<content>` is well formed , is to transform it in `XML` and then use `e4x` to query the informations you wanted.

You have one more thing to be carefull is that your `XML` contains `namespace` so to get the content node you have to take care of that. I suggest you reading the good post about XML [here](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=4) for example.

So the `content` node is inside the `entry` node that have also a `namespace`, but as it 's the same as the root node we can reuse the same `namespace` :

```
var xml:XML=<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="1.0" xml:lang="en">
<title type="text">Google Hot Trends</title>
<subtitle type="text">What are people searching for on Google today?</subtitle>
<id>http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly,2007-08</id>
<link href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly" rel="self"/>
<updated>2010-12-01T14:03:30Z</updated>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<id>2010-12-01T14:03:30Z</id>
<title type="text"><![CDATA[rosa parks, adam levine girlfriend, meet the famous, ...]]></title>

<content type="html"><![CDATA[<ol>
<li><span class="Mild up2"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=rosa+parks&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">rosa parks</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down1"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=adam+levine+girlfriend&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">adam levine girlfriend</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down1"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=meet+the+famous&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">meet the famous</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild equal"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=sons+of+anarchy+season+4&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">sons of anarchy season 4</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild equal"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=victoria+secret+angels&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">victoria secret angels</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up5"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=happy+hanukkah&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">happy hanukkah</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down1"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=katy+perry+victoria+secret+fashion+show&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">katy perry victoria secret fashion show</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down1"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=married+to+the+mob+clothing&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">married to the mob clothing</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down1"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=victoria+secret+models+names+and+pictures&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">victoria secret models names and pictures</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild equal"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=world+aids+day+2010&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">world aids day 2010</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up6"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=shahla+jahed&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">shahla jahed</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild equal"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=interpol&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">interpol</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up18"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=wallis+simpson&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">wallis simpson</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up46"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=chanukah&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">chanukah</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild new"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=hiv+symptoms&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">hiv symptoms</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up6"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=santa+tracker&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">santa tracker</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down8"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=vs+fashion+show+2010&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">vs fashion show 2010</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild down3"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=advent+calendar&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">advent calendar</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up8"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=december+1&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">december 1</a></span></li>
<li><span class="Mild up19"><a href="http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends?q=aids+ribbon&date=2010-12-1&sa=X">aids ribbon</a></span></li>
</ol>
]]></content></entry></feed>;

// get the current namespace from the XML
var ns:Namespace = xml.namespace();

// get and create a new XML from the content node using the previous namespace
var contentXML:XML = new XML(xml.ns::entry.ns::content.toString());

// get all the a node
var anchors:XMLList = contentXML.li.span.a;

// now do what you want with values
for each (var anchor:XML in anchors)
 trace(anchor.@href);
```

Comment: +1: I was going to answer this the same way but kept getting interrupted. Stupid work! :)

Comment: @Robusto, yep we all have to pay the bill ;)